# Windows Mobile - Automated Testing Tool for Non-UI Application

Tags: testing, windows-mobile, compact-framework, automated-tests

I need to automate testing of my windows mobile application. My application does not have any UI. So, normal testing tools which works with random key strokes and mouse clicks will not work here. Are there any tools available for windows mobile to test only background processing?

Comment: What does the app do? What are you trying to test? For instance, if you're doing GPS position logging in your app then automated testing would, presumably, involve requiring movement of the device! How are you defining automated testing? Could you not just use unit testing?

Comment: E.g. 1. It should be able to watch the application for certain things Like, whether SMS, Call Logs are intercepted correctly and data is transffered to server. 2. If device goes out of certain area, it should log it to database. 3. It should be able to communicate to server without problems etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options depending on what level of testing you want.

- Integrated Test

An integrated test aims to test the application in the real world. Therefore you would create all of the "real" things and write code to specifically test to see if your conditions are met. I would believe however, if you're trying to test GPS then this would not be practical. As someone would actually have to move the device around.

- Unit Test by mocking

I've done this before for GPS testing. The idea is that you SANDBOX the object being tested. You ensure that all external references (e.g. anything that isn't the object) are interfaces. You then MOCK these interfaces with "test-only" implementations.

For example I worked on a GPS test where we used an interface called: INmeaInterpreter to fire certain events which would be picked up by a class named PositioningService.
The default implementation was a 3rd party component.
However as INmeaInterpreter was an interface we could create an implementation that instead of using the REAL data uses (for example) an NMEA file to read from. This enabled us to test how the PositioningService worked in certain (and sometimes strange) scenarios.

I would then suggest mocking the other external references. The call to the database can just be a dummy object with a counter for the database call that is incremented if it is called. You could then write a test with an NMEA file that should result in a database call and then at the end of the unit test check that dummy object to see if that call occurred.

We did all the above with horrible MSTest but you could use any testing framework (I recommend NUnit). I'm not sure if there are options to specifically test on the device. We ran all of our tests on desktop as we'd split the code nicely so that device specific code was isolated and could easily be replaced with Desktop equivalents.

Obviously the only problem with unit tests is that *they dont test the hardware*.

---

I would recommend (depending on the size of the project and the team) to do BOTH types of testing but to place the larger emphasis on the unit tests (as they are easier to run/manage).